# Numba JIT memory allocation

Tags: python, numba

I ran the following script:

```
import tracemalloc
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def foo():
    return

tracemalloc.start()
print(f"malloc before calling jitted function {tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()}")
foo()
print(f"malloc after calling jitted function {tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()}")
tracemalloc.stop()
```

with as result:

```
malloc before calling jitted function (0, 0)
malloc after calling jitted function (15085947, 15227418)
```

Do I understand correctly that simply invoking Numba jit takes up 15 MB of memory?

Comment: I don't understand - yes, `numba` is using LLVM compiler for first time (which isn't trivial step). If you measure the invoking again, the result is `malloc after calling jitted function (0, 242)`

Comment: You do understand ;) - and, thanks for the answer

Comment: You should consider using a signature to perform an eager compilation rather than a lazy compilation (done during the first call or when the type of the arguments changes). Here, you can use `@njit("void(void)", cache=True)`.